# What can I do to write forward slashes " / " in Google Docs without opening Help > Search menu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, google

I have a german keyboard MacBook Pro 2019 and I'm using a Portuguese Brazilian ABNT2 keyboard in the system. 
In this configuration, two keys have an native extra feature (not sure if its only on ABNT2):

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> = types a **/**

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> = types a **?**

I need to use these both shortcuts otherwise I do not have any physical key to write a forward slash or question mark.

This is fine in EVERY application but Google office suite. When I try typing a forward slash (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) it opens a `search in menus` menu inside `Help`.

Before coming here, I tried going to Google forums but there is no way to remap that shortcut (in this case, Google considers the shortcut (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>). So I need to bypass it by using some mac feature/software.
**Any suggestions on how to bypass this problem?**

[image]

Comment: It's pretty easy to make a custom abnt2 layout that puts / on another key with https://software.sil.org/ukelele/   If you know where you want it, it would take me couple minutes

Comment: Did not know remapping was that easy, will download this software for sure. Thank you!